# angular material checkbox based next section visibility control issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the material checkbox and material select

the select options are dynamic it's based on previous form fields in the same fromarray

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwyr3u

check the link, please understand the other conditions and check the console

the `Field_Filter` function is called multiple times in a single checkbox click.

anyone suggest me how to solve this issue or provide an alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like since you passed the function Field_Filter() as a paramater for the *ngFor loop, the function is being called on each iteration.

Instead, have the function write to a variable, and use *ngFor to iterate over that variable.

Example:

HTML:
`<mat-option *ngFor="let Fields of FilteredList" [value]="Fields._id"> {{Fields.Name}} </mat-option>`

TS:

```
filteredList: [any]

someEventFunction(Type: any, Index: any) {

this.filteredList = Field_Filter(Type, Index)
```

}

I had a little trouble determining what your desired behavior is, so I wasn't able to get you a complete working example, but I hope this helps!